# responsetext of XMLHttpRequest is null(blank) in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

When I am running the below code in IE it is running fine.

But in mozilla ff, value of layerId is blank because `reqGetSubMenuRef22.responseText` is null at line1.

```
function ajaxFunctionCallGetSubMenuRef22(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers and IE>=7
      reqGetSubMenuRef22 = new XMLHttpRequest();

      reqGetSubMenuRef22.onreadystatechange = processStateChangeGetSubMenuRef22;
      try {
        reqGetSubMenuRef22.open("GET", url, true);
        (( reqGetSubMenuRef22.setRequestHeader && method == "GET" ) ?  reqGetSubMenuRef22.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") : reqGetSubMenuRef22 );
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
      reqGetSubMenuRef22.send(null);
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE    
      reqGetSubMenuRef22 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      if (reqGetSubMenuRef22) {
        reqGetSubMenuRef22.onreadystatechange = processStateChangeGetSubMenuRef22;
        reqGetSubMenuRef22.open("GET", url, true);
        reqGetSubMenuRef22.send();
      }
    }
}

function processStateChangeGetSubMenuRef22() 
{

    if (reqGetSubMenuRef22.readyState == 4) { // Complete
      if (reqGetSubMenuRef22.status == 200) { // OK response
            var textToSplit = reqGetSubMenuRef22.responseText; //line1

        if(textToSplit != null && textToSplit != '') {
                subMenuRef = textToSplit;
                }
            else {
                subMenuRef='';
                }

        layerId=subMenuRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

`processStateChangeGetSubMenuRef22` (not the best func name BTW) is a callback. It is called in the `reqGetSubMenuRef22`'s context, so rather then using `if (reqGetSubMenuRef22.readyState === 4)`, try using `if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)`.
The function is referenced as the handler for the `readystatechange` event, of the variable `reqGetSubMenuRef22`, so that function will be a method of `reqGetSubMenuRef22`, logically (in this case) it is referred to with `this`.

Just to clarify this with an analogy: you don't refer to your living room as *the living room of Some Blvd Nr. 123, whatever town, Whatever country*, do you? When people come over you say *THIS is my living room, this is our home, THIS is where I live*...

Also `reqGetSubMenuRef22` seems to be a global variable in your code, you'll need to address that. Read more on JS's `this` on MDN, and, in case of ajax calls it'll also prove useful to get into `closures`.

---

```
function readyStateCallback()
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        //JSON string?:
        var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        //just txt:
        var resp = this.responseText;
        //HTML?
        document.getElementById('showResponseHere').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        //many more things you can do here...
    }
}
```

why `reqGetSubMenuRef22` doesn't work anymore:

```
function sendRequest(str)
{
    var reqGetSubMenuRef22;//<-- local scope, only accessible in function
    var i;//local, too but different
    //try catch stuff: reqGetSubMenuRef22 is now an ajax object
    for (i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(i);//just an example, you'll see why
    }
    reqGetSubMenuRef22.onreadystatechange = readyStateCallback;//reqGetSubMenuRef22 is still local
    //setup reqGetSubMenuRef22, then:
    reqGetSubMenuRef22.send();
}//end function
```

When the sendRequest function returns, all local variables are GC'ed, variable `i` is erased from memory. `reqGetSubMenuRef22` should be, too, but it has an event attached to it, and this event will trigger a function that is declared in, either, the global scope or another, still existing scope. 
The object is kept alive because JS is listening for an onreadystatechange event on the `reqGetSubMenuRef22` object. So even though it's name is no longer connected to anything, the object is still very much "out there". Not the global object (aka window) calls the `readyStateCallback` function, but the ajax object (`reqGetSubMenuRef22`) does. Hence, you can access the ajax object from inside that function using `this`, which will always point to the object calling the function. (call the same function like so `readyStateCallback();`, this will point to the global object (`window`)) After the callback is finished with it's job, `this`, or the ajax object will be Garbage Collected, unless there are other events due to happen, or it's still referenced somewhere else in your programme.

I'm terrible at explaining this stuff, and I'm all too aware that I'm drastically over simplifying things here, taking shortcuts all over the place. But please do read up on `this` in JavaScript. 
BTW: an object still being kept alive after a function has returned, is in fact a closure of sorts: a variable goes out of scope, but can still be referenced. That's what it boils down to, this allows for some extremely powerful constructs, so I'd urge you to look into this, too!

Comment: Thanx for ur reply.

I replaced reqGetSubMenuRef22 with this. But its still not working. Below is the modified code.

if (this.readyState == 4) { // Complete
       if (this.status == 200) { // OK response
    var textToSplit = reqGetSubMenuRef22.responseText;

Comment: you have to replace ALL occurrences of the `reqGetSubMenuRef22` variable name. Also use `this.responseText`, `this` is a reference to the `reqGetSubMenuRef22` object, which cannot be referenced using it's name because (I hope) it's a function variable, and you're no longer in that function. Also, don't nest your `if` statements the way you do, if you're only checking for `this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200`, just 1 if works just as good and is, IMO, cleaner. I'll update my answer with a template `onreadystatechange` function

Comment: @RakeshK: try leaving out `(( reqGetSubMenuRef22.setRequestHeader && method == "GET" ) ?  reqGetSubMenuRef22.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") : reqGetSubMenuRef22 );` this line, too. And please, please don't use global variables, as you seem to be doing. It's bad practice, imagine sending a request while the 1st request is still being processed, when using globals (using the same variable for both requests), it'll cause errors. If something only works in IE, you should take that as a bad sign. Especially since its no longer the biggest browser, chrome is

Comment: also: in your code: where is the variable `method` coming from?\nAnd as a little side note: `new XMLHttpRequest()` is for all W3C compliant browsers, which IE8 is not, your comment `IE7>=` should read `IE9>=`